# T-SQL Left Join Symbol

Tags: t-sql

What is the symbol (like *=) for doing a left join?
I've got table A and B, must always return all records from table A even if there is no records in table B.

Answer (score 5):

This is the new ansi standard syntax, much clearer imo.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using that operator, as it [was deprecated in Sql Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx), and will be removed in future versions.

You should use ANSI compliant `LEFT JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead.

It was deprecated for a reason. That operator's syntax is confusing (it conflicts with many language's standard overload of "multiply and assign") and is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid any ancient syntax like that.  Rewrite it to include the newer "LEFT OUTER JOIN" and/or "RIGHT OUTER JOIN" syntax:

```
SELECT
    a.*, B.*
    FROM TableA                 a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB  b ON a.id=b.id
```

[Difference between * = and LEFT Outer Join](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/113_2004_5_0_0_428146/Difference-between--and-LEFT-Outer-Join.htm)
from the link:

> In earlier versions of Microsoft® SQL
>   ServerT 2000, left and right outer
>   join conditions were specified in the
>   WHERE clause using the `*=` and `=*`
>   operators. In some cases, this syntax
>   results in an ambiguous query that can
>   be interpreted in more than one way.
>   SQL-92 compliant outer joins are
>   specified in the FROM clause and do
>   not result in this ambiguity. Because
>   the SQL-92 syntax is more precise,
>   detailed information about using the
>   old Transact-SQL outer join syntax in
>   the WHERE clause is not included with
>   this release. The syntax may not be
>   supported in a future version of SQL
>   Server. Any statements using the
>   Transact-SQL outer joins should be
>   changed to use the SQL-92 syntax

Answer (score 0):

Besides of that, use of ANSI standard syntax LEFT [OUTER] JOIN for joins simplifies looking for errors a lot, believe me.
It allows also for clearer distinction between filters in WHERE clause and join operands.
I would recommend also use ANSI syntax for inner joins.